# Has there been any R&D(let alone progress) in the development of gamma voltaic cells?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays, isotopes

I ask this because it is my understanding that gamma rays form ion tracks and oxygen radicals when gamma emitting material is immersed in an aqueous solution. Cesium-137 is a very strong gamma ray source with a half-life of 30 years. Beta cells are inefficient but gamma rays have considerably more energy. So to harvest it you would need a lot of heavy metal shielding. How effective are gamma emitters at radiolysis of water to form hydrogen and oxygen gas?

Comment: *Cesium-137 is a very strong gamma ray source with a half-life of 30 years.* Not sure what you mean by "very strong" here. A 137Cs source can have any strength. It depends on what amount you have. *Beta cells are inefficient but gamma rays have considerably more energy.* No, beta and gamma radiation occur with roughly the same energy scale in most cases, on the order of 1 MeV. Anyway, this is kind of an interesting question, if I'm following what you have in mind. Plutonium RTGs have few applications because plutonium is legally restricted bomb material, so one could use a beta source.

Comment: @BenCrowell Plutonium RTGs use [Pu-238](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238), which is not fissile. True, it can be converted to Pu-239, the primary fissile isotope of plutonium, by neutron irradiation, but separating the isotopes is difficult, and trying to get a high proportion of Pu-239 by irradiation risks creating too much Pu-240, an undesirable contaminant for weapons use. It's much easier to produce Pu-239 from U-238. Mind you, producing high quality Pu-238 isn't exactly easy either, and world stockpiles are quite low, but at least it's now back in production.

Comment: @BenCrowell Pu-239 is fissile but has a substantially slower decay rate than Pu-238 and Cs-137 so it is not useful for nuclear batteries. What I am talking about here is harvesting the gamma radiation from Cs-137, which has a half life of ~30 years, into electrical energy. One proposed way is to use compton scattering by having alternating layers of lead and aluminum to create a potential difference....

Comment: ...but what I'm suggesting is having a wet cell so that the Cs-137 would be Cs-137 chloride disolved in water. The water would absorb some of the gamma ray energy and would converted to H202. So the proposed device would actually be more of an electrochemical fuel cell than purely voltaic cell. Cs-137 is a highly dangerous byproduct of nuclear waste but releases a lot of energy so it could be put to use.